# Why is the repetition of "is" in these type of sentences?

Tags: word-usage

> The cool thing is is that ...

Link: [@5:11 of this video.](https://youtu.be/T4M7l8X9wDQ?t=311)

I hear many native English speakers repeat the word "is" when they say sentences like that. I don't think it's related to the grammar. I feel like it's a more of a filler word and it's not really needed. At the same time, it's not a stuttering because many native English speakers do it. Why do they repeat it? Is it related to a specific accent?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13056/the-thing-is-is-that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the *double is* construction.

The what is implied:

> {What} the thing is, is I'm in a hurry"
>
> {What} I thought was, is/was that..."

NB It doesn't necessarily involve a double "is" or a "thing" (as per my examples).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_copula

Worth mentioning, that is it also technically incorrect.