# Use if "there" in a question?

Tags: adverbs, questions

I need to know what kind of stores or entertainment i can find on Broadway. Should I ask: "What is there on Broadway?" or "What is on Broadway?" Can "there" be used in a question?

Comment: ... entertainment halls, sorry

Comment: You can edit your question - click "edit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use "there" in questions as you've used it here -- "What is there on Broadway?" and "What is on Broadway?" mean the same thing, though the first seems a smidge more natural/idiomatic to me.

That said, if someone asked me "What's on Broadway?", absent some other context, I would interpret the speaker to be asking "What shows are currently being performed in the Broadway theater district?" rather than "What stores and entertainment halls are there on Broadway?" I'm a bit of a theater buff, so that may be coloring my interpretation, but regardless, "What's there to do on/around Broadway?" would unambiguously communicate that you're asking something more general than that.

Comment: If speaker wishes to know "What shows are currently being performed in the Broadway theater district?" I think he'd ask *What's **on on** Broadway?* (native speakers have no problem repeating prepositions like that). If there was just a *single* preposition, that would have to associate with "Broadway" (as a "preposition of location"), which kinda loses the "active / available" sense conveyed by the ***first*** (of two) instance in my version (by far the most likely context). I think it comes down to whether questioner cares more about the shows or the location (probably the former).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I am a native speaker and "What's on on Broadway?" sounds super bad to me -- not necessarily because of the double prepositions (you're right, they're fine in some contexts) but because it's just not natural to use "What's on [in/on some place]?" as the question to inquire about something like that, at least not in the (AmE) dialects I'm familiar with. I've certainly never heard "What's on on Broadway?" used and it would sound like an error or stutter if I heard someone say it instead of the much more natural "What's on Broadway?" (which I have heard before)

Comment: I do think that the "What is there on Broadway?" is more likely to be interpreted as a question about the location than "What's on Broadway?" is.

Comment: [*We've got a great guide **on** what's **on on** BBC One and Two.*](https://www.liverpoolecho.co.uk/news/tv/whats-tv-march-tv-shows-11012847) I'd much prefer the first ***on*** there to be ***to***, but that's simply because in my version of English it's the wrong preposition. I have no problem with *to be **on*** = *currently or scheduled soon to be **on show*** being coupled to a "location" *(**on** Broadway, **on** the TV)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica May be a dialectical difference then -- I'm American, and that source is British. Use of "What on on X?" sounds weird to me in your example as well, but it's significantly less bad for TV programs than for Broadway -- perhaps because you could speak of a TV being "on" or ask simply "What's on?" for TV programs, whereas that language isn't generally used to the same extent wrt Broadway.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But to my ear, *What's on TV?* and *What's on tonight?* are effectively "different" prepositions, so I barely even perceive *What's on on TV tonight?* as being "repetitious". On the other hand, when I hear someone say *The [thing is is](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/213049/why-is-the-repetition-of-is-in-these-type-of-sentences) that blah blah* it usually seems to be in an *American* accent. And that one I nearly *always* notice, because I see no justification for it at all.

Comment: I mean, on a linguistics level, you're 100% right re: the two different uses of "on" -- "What's on tonight?" isn't using "on" as a preposition but as part of a phrasal verb "to be on" -- but my point is more that, at least in my understanding, "to be on" is not really used with theatre productions in the way that it is with tv programs, which is why "What's on on Broadway" sounds bad to me. The double-is construction you describe is unrelated to the current question, but [its usage and syntactic features are well-attested in several English dialects](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/double-is).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can.

"There is" is used to say that something exists. In this construction, the word "there" does not mean a place. Example: "There is a shopping mall on Broadway."

To ask whether something exists, you can say "Is there ...?"
Example: "Is there a subway station on Broadway?"
Answer: "There is a subway station on Broadway." - or "Yes."

To ask which things exist, you can say "What is there ...?"
Example: "What is there on Broadway?"
Example: "What is there in the shopping mall on Broadway?"
Possible answer: "There is a McDonald's in the shopping mall on Broadway." - or "A McDonald's."

(I don't know what there *actually* is on Broadway, so my answers are generic)

---

You can also ask (most commonly) "Why is there ...?" and "When is there ...?", and less commonly "How is there ...?" and "Where is there ...?". (I don't think I've ever heard "Who is there ...?")